# Guess full date based on partial date entered in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

Doing some code in JavaScript/jQuery and I need to have it where the user can enter a somewhat partial date string and have JavaScript figure out the full date.

For example, if the user enters  "5/24" it should return "5/24/2011" (the current year). If the user enters "5/24/2004" it should return just that.

```
duedate = Date.parse(qadueparse);
duedatelit = new Date(duedate);
duedatelit = Number(duedatelit.getMonth()+1) + '/' + 
    Number(duedatelit.getDate()) + '/' + Number(duedatelit.getFullYear());
```

This above code works when the user supplies a full string, however it seems to screw up on me when the user types "5/24" or some other partial string. It returns a year of 2001.

Can anyone help me out?

Turning once again to StackOverflow for my programming needs; thank you, everyone, in this vibrant community for supporting each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date object can accept a deconstructed date for instantiation:

```
var d = new Date(2011, 7, 13, 15, 59, 0); // Jul 13th, 3:59:00pm
```

You can rip apart the partial date and fill in the blanks yourself. However, what is 3/7? March 7th? July 3rd? Worse yet, 3/5/7 - which is year, which is month, which is day?

---

comment followup:

If it's always m/d, then you just split on the `/`, giving you m and d values.

```
provided = '5/24';
parts = provided.split('/');

month = parts[0]; // 5
day = parts[1]; // 24

today = new Date();

your_date = new Date(today.getFullYear(), month, day); // new date object for 2011/5/24
```

Comment: Obviously, for stuff like "3/5/7" it can just reject it. Otherwise, we're going by "m/d". I'm not understanding what you mean by a deconstructed date. In my code snippet, qadueparse is basically something like "5/24". I want it to be able to intelligently figure out I mean this year. Could you elaborate on your method please?

Comment: Edited the answer, since comments are a bad place to put code blocks.

Comment: Thanks; this helps tremendously! However, what if there is a possibility of a year included as well? Eg. it could be 5/24, or 5/24/2009. Even more awesome if it could also catch 2009/5/24 (the year would always be 4-digits)

Comment: You'd need to do some checking first to see if it's got 2 or 3 components, plus figuring which component has 4 digits

Comment: I would a) check for first number, 2-4 digits, b) grab length of first number, c) using length, substr() to remove that, d) check using indexOf() to see if there is a slash, e) if there is a slash, remove it, and f) repeating. Is this the smartest way to do this?